# How do I fix my Collision so I could stand on a box without Falling from it

Tags: python, pygame

What I am trying to do here is make my collision detect allow me to jump on a square but it doesn't seem to work. Its a the very bottom of the main loop.

```
# --- COLLISION is at the bottom of main loop
# ------
# this is a pygame module that I imported
import pygame
pygame.init()

# this is just my screen I created win defines it
win = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))
# this is my caption for my game 
pygame.display.set_caption("Just Tryna learn Something")


# these are my coordinates for my enemy where it will spawn
cordx = 300
cordy = 300
heights = 70
widths = 70


# my Player Coordinate and its speed and and its Jump 
x = 200
y = 200
height = 40
width = 40
speed = 5
isJump = False
jumpCount = 10


# main loop
# main loop for my game
running  = True
while running:
    pygame.time.delay(100)
    win.fill((0,0,0))
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


    # this here  draws my player in my window
    Player = pygame.draw.rect(win, (140, 0,150), (x, y, height, width))
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # this here draws my enemy 
    Enemy = pygame.draw.rect(win, (90,90,90), (cordx, cordy, heights, widths))
#=-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
#-------------------------------------------------------------------
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        x -= speed
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        x += speed

    # this here is my functions for movement  and Jumping 
   if not(isJump):
        if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
            y -= speed
        if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            y += speed
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            isJump = True
    else:
        if jumpCount >= -10:
            y -= (jumpCount * abs(jumpCount)) * 0.5
            jumpCount -= 1
        else: 
            jumpCount = 10
            isJump = False


    # COLLISION here is my collision detect and collision 
its suppose to make me stand on the square with my little box when I jump on it
but it doesnt seem to work (Enemy) is the big box and (Player) is the little box
    if Player.colliderect(Enemy):
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (150,0,140), (50, 50, 20, 70))
    if Player.top >= 375 and Player.top <= 370:
        x = 375

   # ---------------------------------------------------------

    pygame.display.update()


pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Hi Habib, welcome to the site! Take the [tour] if you haven't already. I've edited your question a bit to make it fit in better here, but there are some further improvements that I think only you can make. To start with, This is a lot of code! Can you cut out any of the irrelevant parts, making it a [mcve]? You say your code doesn't work, but you don't say how exactly. Is it raising an exception? If so, please give the full traceback. Is it doing something wrong? Describe what it's doing and what you expect it to do instead. Please [edit] the question to make any of these improvements you can!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Continuously let the player fall down. Add a variable `fall = 0` and the variable to `y` and increment `fall` in every frame, if the player is not jumping. A jump ends, if the player reaches the maximum jump height (`jumpCount == 0`):

```py
if not isJump:

    y += fall
    fall += 1

    # [...]

else:
    if jumpCount > 0:
        y -= (jumpCount * abs(jumpCount)) * 0.5
        jumpCount -= 1
    else: 
        jumpCount = 10
        isJump = False
```

Limit the player to the bottom of the window (500), and the top of the block by setting the `y` coordinate of the player:

```py
Player.topleft = (x, y)
collide = False
if Player.colliderect(Enemy):
    y = Enemy.top - Player.height
    collide = True
if Player.bottom >= 500:
    y = 500 - Player.height
    collide = True
```

It is only allowed to jump, if the player stands on the ground or on the block:

```py
if collide:
    if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        isJump = True
    fall = 0
```

Furthermore use [`pygame.time.Clock()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock) and [`tick()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick), instead of `pygame.time.delay()` for a smooth movement. Control the speed by the flops per second (`FPS`):

```py
FPS = 60
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

running  = True
while running:

    clock.tick(FPS)
    #pygame.time.delay(100)
```

See the example:

[image]

```py
# --- COLLISION is at the bottom of main loop
# ------
# this is a pygame module that I imported
import pygame
pygame.init()

# this is just my screen I created win defines it
win = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))
# this is my caption for my game 
pygame.display.set_caption("Just Tryna learn Something")

# these are my coordinates for my enemy where it will spawn
cordx = 300
cordy = 350
heights = 70
widths = 70

# my Player Coordinate and its speed and and its Jump 
x = 200
y = 200
height = 40
width = 40
speed = 5
isJump = False
jumpCount = 10
fall = 0

FPS = 60
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# main loop
# main loop for my game
running  = True
while running:
    clock.tick(FPS)
    #pygame.time.delay(100)

    win.fill((0,0,0))
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    # this here  draws my player in my window
    Player = pygame.draw.rect(win, (140, 0,150), (x, y, height, width))
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # this here draws my enemy 
    Enemy = pygame.draw.rect(win, (90,90,90), (cordx, cordy, heights, widths))
#=-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
#-------------------------------------------------------------------
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        x -= speed
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        x += speed

    # this here is my functions for movement  and Jumping 
    if not isJump:

        y += fall
        fall += 1

        Player.topleft = (x, y)
        collide = False
        if Player.colliderect(Enemy):
            collide = True
            y = Enemy.top - Player.height
            if Player.right > Enemy.left and  Player.left < Enemy.left:
                x = Enemy.left - Player.width
            if Player.left < Enemy.right and  Player.right > Enemy.right:
                x = Enemy.right

        if Player.bottom >= 500:
            collide = True
            y = 500 - Player.height

        if collide:
            if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
                isJump = True
            fall = 0

    else:
        if jumpCount > 0:
            y -= (jumpCount * abs(jumpCount)) * 0.5
            jumpCount -= 1
        else: 
            jumpCount = 10
            isJump = False

    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Thank you so much tried to solve the problem by watching tutorials they didnt make sense stumbled on this site and already got the help and understanding thank you,!

Comment: also one more question my player is taking to much time in air the jumping isnt smooth is there a way to fix that?

Comment: I did ok I feel like asking one more question will be annoying but could I also do that for right and left of my enemy square like if I touch it I cant go throw those to

Comment: @HabibIsmail You have to restrict the `x` coordinate to the `.left` or `.right` of  `Enemy`. I've added some code to after `if Player.colliderect(Enemy):`

Comment: this is an old post but is there a way to fix [this collision](https://gyazo.com/3fae109d3f19697b4b04844e7d8d3abf)  so it could like collide the bottom  to so I don't go up like that [my collision script](https://gyazo.com/fb7b9d48040f2ad045921760d533ce09)